# How change routing configuration from angular2 rc2 to rc4

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm currently using version RC2 of Angular2. I found that there are many changes in routing in RC4 version

What is the best way to migrate from rc2 to rc4

I just want to create RouteApp and I got some errors:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you update your package.json seems like this

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
  "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
  "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
  "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
  "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
  "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
  "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
  "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
  "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
  "systemjs": "0.19.26",
  "zone.js": "^0.6.12"  },
```

And open your terminal and type `npm install`.

Yes that simple . Hope it will help you :)

---

**EDIT:**

New Router is beta now. Hence changed 3.0.0-alpha.8 to 3.0.0-beta.1

Refer more details here- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: Thanks @Sanket for your input :)